# Directive in Angular 5 for return html

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive

How can I return small html piece by directive. This is what I am trying to do:

```
<app-icon glyph="music"><app-icon>
```

should be replaced by:

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphico-music' aria-hidden='true'></span>
```

And my wrong directive:

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[app-icon]"
})
export class IconDirective {

  constructor(value: string) {
    return "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-" +value + "' aria-hidden='true'></span>";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on previous answer I solved that in that way:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "app-icon"
})
export class IconDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() glyph;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
      `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-${this.glyph} aria-hidden='true'></span>`);
  }

}
```

`ngOnInit` is required because `@Input glyph` is not initialized in contstructor

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ElementRef` from `@angular/core` :

```
 constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
 this._el.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
  '<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-" +value + "' aria-hidden='true'></span>');
 }
```

Comment: How this directive need to be declared to be able to use `<app-icon glyph="music"><app-icon>` in html?

Comment: Ok I know already. You need to have: `selector: "app-icon"` - withouot brackets `[ ]`

Comment: With the `[appIcon]` selector (camelCase for directive selectors) you can add it to a div like this `<div appIcon></div>`